# Datatable - Buttons, length and search in same same colum

Tags: datatable

I have a simple [**Datatable**](https://datatables.net/). In this table i have buttons, length and search box, like this

[image]

The DOM code is

```
   dom: "lBftrip",
```

So i need to positioning this elements in same column. As we can see the length in one column and rest of elements in other.

How can i can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

This resolve the question

```
  dom: "<'row'<'col-xs-12'B<'col-xs-6'l>frtip>>",
```